# How to suspend/resume emulated HID device?

Tags: drivers, usb, usbhid

I have an emulated USB keyboard using the [HID Gadget Driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/gadget_hid.html) that I use to inject input into another computer. I have enabled remote wakeup in the USB configuration descriptor.

Using HID system control, I am able to put the other computer to sleep. However, once the other computer is asleep, I can no longer inject input.

My understanding is that a normal USB device would send a resume signal to wake up the host, but that is usually done at the firmware level.

Is there a way to send a resume signal through the HID gadget driver?

If there is a better place to ask this, please let me know.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux or other OS are you using?

Comment: @user68186 I'm using Open Embedded 4 Tegra. https://github.com/OE4T/linux-tegra-4.9